# GIT Squash: Does it cause issues?

Tags: git

Let's say we have a feature branch called `feature-branch`. Developers branch of this branch for their tickets and then open a PR to `feature-brach`.

If the following happens:

1. Developer A branches off `feature-branch` and develops on a branch `ticket-a`
2. Developer B then goes to `feature-branch` and squashes two previous commits into one.
3. Developer A goes to merge `ticket-a` into `feature-branch`

Will there be a merge conflict or any issues? Since the `ticket-a` branch will have two commits where as the `feature-branch` will only have one as the two commits were squashed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have something like:

```
Ancestor -- A -- B
                  \-- C
```

And you do a squash:

```
Ancestor -- AB
        \-- A -- B -- C
```

You would be changing your history branch and creating a new commit with a new hash. Therefore, if you attempt to merge those two branches, git will try and find their common ancestor and begin your merge from there. But `A` doesn't contain all the changes `AB` does, which can cause conflicts.

To fix this, I suggest you rebase your other branch so it will contain the squashed commit. You can accomplish this with [rebase onto](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) from your second branch:

> git rebase --onto AB C branch2